# Oracle change column datatype from varray

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes, varray

In Oracle database I have two schemas with two tables that mirror each other, except for one column which in both tables is varray of numbers, but in schema A it's `A.VARRAY`, and in schema B it's `B.VARRAY`.

As a result I'm unable to migrate data between tables, since they have **inconsistent datatypes**.

Is there any way to change column datatype from `A.varray` to `B.varray` without losing data?

Comment: Please show DDL of your VARRAYs. As far as I remember they can be converted implicitly in case of equal types in them.

Comment: Both are the same, just existing in different schemas: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_TYPE AS VARRAY(5000) OF NUMBER(1)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `cast(col as B.VARRAYTYPE)`:

```sql
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_TYPE_1 AS VARRAY(5000) OF NUMBER(1);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_TYPE_2 AS VARRAY(5000) OF NUMBER(1);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table t1 (a V_TYPE_1);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(v_type_1(1,2,3,4,5));

1 row created.

SQL> create table t2 (a V_TYPE_2);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t2 select cast(a as v_type_2) from t1;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t2;

A
-------------------------
V_TYPE_2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

`CAST` it is, I agree with Sayan. Though, as there are two users involved, there are some in-between steps required - **grant execute on type** being most important, I'd say. Here's an example.

My users are `scott` and `mike`. Each of them has the same table description. `scott` is supposed to insert rows into `mike`'s table.

Connected as `scott`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create or replace type v_type as varray(5000) of number(1);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table test (id number, a v_type);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test(id, a) values (1, v_type(1));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Connected as `mike`: uses the same type as `scott`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> create or replace type v_type as varray(5000) of number(1);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table test (id number, a v_type);

Table created.

SQL> grant insert on test to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Connected as `scott`, trying to insert row(s) into `mike`'s table:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> insert into mike.test (id, a) select id, a from test;
insert into mike.test (id, a) select id, a from test
                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MIKE.V_TYPE got SCOTT.V_TYPE
```

Let's try `CAST`:

```
SQL> insert into mike.test (id, a) select id, cast(a as mike.v_type) from test;
insert into mike.test (id, a) select id, cast(a as mike.v_type) from test
                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL>
```

In order to make it work, `mike` has to **grant execute** on their type to `scott`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> grant execute on v_type to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Finally, it *works*:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> insert into mike.test (id, a) select id, cast(a as mike.v_type) from test;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to add a column to one of the tables, populate the new column with values from the other column, say through an update statement, then drop old column?

T1(c1 V_TYPE_1);
T2(c1 V_TYPE_2);

(1) Add column to T2:
T2(c1 V_TYPE_2, c2 V_TYPE_1);

(2) Update T2 so c1 and c2 are the same values for every row.

(3) Drop old column from T2:
T2(c2 V_TYPE_1);

This solution would be a little easier if the table was not active. If the table was active you will want to add a trigger so that the two columns are in sync.